# How do I find directories with a question mark in the name? Escaping not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, find, escape-characters

I am try to find directories like

```
services-client?.git
```

using the command

```
find . -name *\?.git
```

but get all directories ending in .git

What I'm doing is downloading a file from amazon s3 and in creating directory based on the lines in the file. I generate a file in excel then copy the values into notepad and finally upload the file to amazon s3.

I add the .git extensions before creating the directory. This might mean that I have a line ending problem in the downloaded file.

Comment: Try quoting the string e.g. "find . -name '*\?.git'"

Comment: Try `find [path] -type d *\?.git`

Comment: Or enclose in singles quotes?

Comment: `find . -type d -name *\?.git` gives me all directories including the directories with question marks. and `find . -type d -name '*\?.git'` gives me no result.

Comment: If you have CR or other bad char in the file, you might create a name that `ls` *displays* as question-mark but is **not in fact question-mark**. Try `ls -1b` or `ls -1b partialmatch*git` (numeral one and lowercase bee) to see exactly what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to find all directories with a question mark in name:

```
find . -type d -name '*\?*'
```

Comment: I get an empty directory listing when I try this.